# Delete all types created by a user

Tags: schema, oracle-10g, plsql, sqlplus

In Oracle 10g, how do I delete all the types owned by a specific user? This is the view that gives me the types I want to drop:`SELECT type_name FROM user_types;`

Answer (score 1):

Use a query to generate a `drop type` script [in SQL Plus]:

```
set lines 132
set head off
set pages 0

spool drop_types.sql

select 'drop type '||type_name||';'
from user_types;

spool off
```

Then execute the script in SQL Plus:

```
@drop_types.sql
```